# How to convert from application.properties to application.yml in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

I have a very simple Spring Boot app and I have application.properties, and now I want to move to application.yml

This is the application.yml file:

```
spring:
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee_directory
        username: student
        password: Password123
```

So I've deleted application.properties file and I've written the application.yml file. If I run the app I get this exception:

```
   20:31:22.446 [restartedMain] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load property source from location 'classpath:/application.yml'
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:524)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadForFileExtension(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:473)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:443)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$null$6(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:425)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$load$7(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:425)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:422)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:202)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:186)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:176)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:164)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:340)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202)
    at com.dgs.springboot.SpringBootRESTJPA.SpringBootRestJPAApplication.main(SpringBootRestJPAApplication.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: while scanning for the next token
found character '\t(TAB)' that cannot start any token. (Do not use \t(TAB) for indentation)
 in 'reader', line 2, column 1:
        datasource:
    ^

    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:419)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:227)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseBlockMappingValue.produce(ParserImpl.java:586)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:158)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.checkEvent(ParserImpl.java:148)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:124)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeValueNode(Composer.java:236)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingChildren(Composer.java:227)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingNode(Composer.java:215)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:144)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getNode(Composer.java:85)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getData(BaseConstructor.java:123)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml$1.next(Yaml.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.process(YamlProcessor.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.process(YamlProcessor.java:134)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedYamlLoader.load(OriginTrackedYamlLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader.load(YamlPropertySourceLoader.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadDocuments(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:497)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

I think I need to make other modification to my code to use this application.yml file but I don't know what to do?

This is pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.dgs.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootRESTHibernate</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringBootRESTHibernate</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <!-- Add work around for Eclipse bug -->
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
          <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- This is used for packaging and running our app -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Any feedback will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is the full stack

Comment: @Darren I just updated it

Comment: The message is quite clear: `found character '\t(TAB)' that cannot start any token. (Do not use \t(TAB) for indentation)`.

Comment: Thank you JB Nizet!

Answer (score 42):

I built an online conversion tool (https://env.simplestep.ca/) that converts between spring boot yaml, properties and environment variables--using [spring boot's relaxed binding rules](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.environment-variables)

[image]

Comment: Good contribution, but does not accept comments and doesn't properly convert indexed properties (`my.property[0]=x`,  `my.property[1]=y`, etc.)

Comment: @PauloMerson, should handle the indexed properties (see the properties example). I have an open issue for ignoring comments. PR welcome!

Comment: Be carefull. with sending sensitive information to an online tool.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the command line tool [props2yaml](https://github.com/Codearte/props2yaml) for generic automatic (and correct) translation from properties to yaml.

Answer (score 3):

for `intellij-IDEA` : go to file > settings > plugins then search for a plugin called: `Properties to YAML Converter`. Install it and After that restart your IDE then right click the application.properties file and you will get an option called "convert to yaml"

Comment: This tool is suck, it cannot convert array type

Answer (score 2):

Check if you are using tabs for indentation. 
This is not permitted by the [YAML spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2777534):

> To maintain portability, tab characters must not be used in indentation, since different systems treat tabs differently. Note that most modern editors may be configured so that pressing the tab key results in the insertion of an appropriate number of spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you use **Eclipse** or **STS** it's very simple.

Just open the context menu on the `.properties` file and choose "Convert to Yaml file".

The file will be converted automatically.  If there is not this feature on your context menu you need to install Yaml plugin from

```
Help menu-> Eclipse market place.
```

Comment: Which yaml plugin on the market place? There are a bunch.

Comment: I had Spring Boot project and Plug in & it was very easy to convert using this option , thx !

Answer (score 0):

I think your `datasource.url` value needs to be in quotes, due to the ':'. Try this:

```
  ...
  url: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee_directory'
  ...
```

Also, as was pointed about above, you should use spaces for indentation; typically, two spaces per level.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is just an additional answer, might help other developers.

I found a better and easy tool to convert properties file to YML file.
[convert from properties to yml](https://localise.biz/free/converter)

You have to upload your .properties file and then Choose To **YML** file option and it will generate a pretty good yml file.
This tool supports many other formats also like Yml to XML, Yml to Properties, CSV, JSON, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, it removes all comments and doesn't properly convert indexed properties (`my.property[0]=x`,  `my.property[1]=y`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

File `application.yml` must be in the root folder `resources`.

Comment: Since the location of the file wasn't mentioned, I'd rather comment and ask instead of answering immediately.

Answer (score -2):

Just for others looking a similar answer, in a Spring project running in IntelliJ, it works just change the extension of the application.properties to application.yml. In my case the file was empty, so I didn't have to change anything and I could use application.yml propertly.