# .properties to .yaml conversion while preserving comment?

Tags: spring-boot, visual-studio-code, yaml, properties-file

Here is an earlier discussion, which asks about - [How to convert from application.properties to application.yml in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57465865/how-to-convert-from-application-properties-to-application-yml-in-spring-boot)

The solutions discussed above work but there is a limitation with `#comments`.
Comments (`#comments`) in  .properties file are not carried forward in to .yaml file after conversion.

So want to check if there is any tool (online/ide based/offline) that supports conversion with comments carried forward into .yaml file.

Comment: this is something very simple you write in Python

Comment: @rioV8 - could you expand your comment in to a answer with more details.

Answer (score -1):

- read each line of the properties file

  - keep track of the comments
  - put the grouped property in a data structure together with the comment
- write the data structure to the YAML file

Comment: could you add any source code for your solution. ++1,